# host not found in upstream "app" nginx not serving the app stuck on welcome page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn

Its my first time setting up nginx and unicorn.

My capistrano deployment went through and everything succeeded.

```
here is my unicorn.rb

#app_dir = File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)
#shared_dir = File.expand_path('../../../shared/', __FILE__)

preload_app true 
worker_processes 4
timeout 30
working_directory "home/deploy/appname"
shared_dir = "home/deploy/appname/shared"

# Set up socket location 
# by default unicorn listens on 8080
listen "#{shared_dir}/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Logging
stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# Set master PID location
pid "#{shared_dir}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

#must set preload app true to use before/after fork
before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  
  #before forking, this is suppose to kill the master process that belongs to the oldbin
  #enables 0 downtime to deploy

  old_pid = "#{shared_dir}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

# before_exec do |server|
#   ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "#{app_dir}/Gemfile"
# end
```

my nginx conf at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}


http {  
       sendfile on;
       tcp_nopush on;
       tcp_nodelay on;
       keepalive_timeout 65;
       types_hash_max_size 2048;
       
 
       include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
       default_type application/octet-stream;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


       gzip on;
       gzip_disable "msie6";

       include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
       include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

my default file at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
upstream app_server {
  #path to unicorn sock file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/deploy/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

    server {
        listen 80;
    
        root /home/deploy/appname;
    
     try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
    
        #click tracking
        access_log /var/log/nginx/appname_access.log combined;
    
        error_log /var/log/nginx/appname_error.log;
    
        location @app {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass http://app;
        }
    
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        keepalive_timeout 10;
    }
```

when I do this

```
deploy@localhost:~$ sudo nginx -s reload
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:46
```

When I head into

```
/shared/tmp/sockets
```

I don't have a file in there. I don't think I should create it manually. I am using capistrano 3. Am I suppose to generate this file?

I am using

```
require 'capistrano3/unicorn' #in capfile
```

in deploy.rb

## symbolic files and directories

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets log bin vendor/bundle public/system}

#just pointing to our unicorn.rb
set :unicorn_config_path, "config/unicorn.rb"

#capistrano tasks and processes

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'unicorn:restart'
    end
  end

  after :finishing, "deploy:cleanup"

end
```

I put my cap file here because I notice no log on unicorn restart in my cap production deploy log. I am not sure if this helps.

I made sure the working_directory matches the root in the default nginx page.
I made sure the listen in unicorn matches the upstream app server unix in the default page.
I made sure the nginx.conf file included the default config nginx page in sites-enabled.

Answer (score 9):

Well this is 6 months old, but I'm going to answer it anyways. The issue is  proxy_pass in @app in sites_enabled/default. It's trying to pass to the upstream server http://app , but you don't have that upstream set, you have it named app_server.

You need to rename:
proxy_pass http://app

to:
proxy_pass http://app_server